# Optimising a business strategy

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, finance, word-problem

My brother in year 8 was given this scenario:

"You sell chairs and make sales at monthly intervals. You start with $16,000.

Each month, 17000 people buy chairs, The market average price for chairs is $72.

Chairs cost $40 each when you buy 400 or more, and 35 dollars each when you buy 1000 or more.

Premium chairs cost 45 dollars each when you buy 400 or more, and 40 dollars each when you buy 1000 or more.

Your business sets the price of chairs. The price must be between $24-$150. For every $4 under the market average, your business gains 0.5% of the market.

For each $0.50 over the market average, your business loses 0.05% of its customers when selling standard chairs, and 0.01% of its customers when selling standard chairs, and 0.01% of its customers when selling premium chairs.

For every 1000 chairs sold in a month, your business must pay an employee $5000.10% of sales must go to the government for GST.

Your business may take out one loan at a time. You can only loan out as much money as you currently have. The loan compounds monthly at a rate of 18% per month. You must pay the entire loan off in a single month. The loan will continue to compound until you repay it.

Make the most profit possible within a year "

I think the purpose of this was for them to try different strategies and play around with them to see what works best. However, I'm wondering how this could be optimized to give the best possible result. As the problem is very convoluted I assume one could maybe use a program to simulate different situations however I wouldn't know how to do this. Feel free to simplify the problem if you wish to try it (eg. Don't use GST, premium chairs, or loans). I'm interested to see how a situation with multiple variables (the price each year) can be optimized.

Comment: Absolute profit by the end of the year

Comment: Are we also supposed to consider game-theoretic scenario of $x$ competitors in the market? For eg: the strategy would be different in a monopoly versus a market with 2 or 3 players.

Comment: No, don't think you need to worry about that, assume competitors' decisions have no effect and the average market price is always the same. (Everyone just works to get their best individual profit)

Comment: I think this can be considered a $n$-player repeated game (with 12 rounds, one for each month) and the problem can be formulated as a multi-round zero-sum game and use MinMax algorithm to calculate the optimal strategy and total payoffs.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about that. The game is single-player, however, and other decisions have no outcome on your strategy/outcome. All your 'competitors' are hypothetical. Not sure if I made that clear.

Comment: Can you reread and correct your question? There are some typos and duplicate sentences.